# How will CORS respond if request is made from user browser

Tags: javascript, php, server, cors

I have question in mind which I tried to find the answer but there is no any exact answer I found .
We have a server supposed "A" which implements backend services and another server "B" which implements frontend.

For CORS we set "header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [B]')".
Now the frontend server is added in cross origin access list.
A user opens a page which have some javascript that make a request on server "A" for some data.

Will the server "A" entertain it or reject the request. and if YES, Why it will entertain it becuase the request if made from the user browser.

Thanks in advance for helping me to understand this.

Comment: CORS is checked by the client, not the server. The server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: B`, and the client checks if its domain is B.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the help. if client check the CORS then how it will protect the server "A"

Comment: If the user goes to a malicious website C, and it tries to send an AJAX request to A, the browser will block it.

Comment: @Barmar I got it. I really thankful to you. you really cleared my concept. I also just read the MDN documentation again carefully after reading your answer and you are absolutely right.
thanks

Comment: @Barmar please put it in the answer I will mark it as correct as your answer is more appropriate I think

Comment: There are almost certainly old questions that explain this process much better than I can. But I don't have a link to one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236107/discussion-between-imran-ahmed-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

If server A whitelists Server B, then server B can for example run an iframe with a link to server A without error.

If by default, server A blocks every other server, then no other server can run an iframe with a link to server A.

The code below shows that google by default blocks iframe and that you are not a whitelisted server.

```html
<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://google.com" style="height:100%;width:100%"></iframe>
```

If you are on server B and use an iframe that goes to server A then it will work.

NOTE: There are ways to bypass the header altogether.

Comment: I don't think CORS affects iframes, only AJAX requests sent from JavaScript.

Comment: Sadly, it does. Both CORS and X-Frame-Options block iframes.

Comment: I would love to know how you can bypass the header on a browser did you find a hack on the content security policy

Comment: It is not an easy task to bypass it. At least, if you don't have a server. Right now, for a normal webpage, take a look at this [Github](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass) project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on

`domain1.com`

And you reach

`dominio.com`

The browser makes an options request, you can check the options request in the network tab. Basically the browser pings the server the  server responds with a 204 status code no content and the browser checks the access-control-allow-origin and if its value is equals to the origin of the current tab the browser fetches the actual request, but if the value of it is not the same as the current origin then the browser blocks the request throws a cors error. Servers don’t know anything about a cors error it doesn’t exist, the browser is the one causing it. If the server is open to the world it will handle the request of anybody  that can reach it.

To answer the question both servers would handle the request, but only the one that has the correct header is going to be call, so it depends on the browser